# A question on where a chord $AB$ inside an ellipse with a point $P$ on it, attains its maximum for the ratio $\frac{AP}{PB}$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

My question is this. Given an ellipse $E$ with equation $\frac{x^2}{9}$+$\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ and $P(\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$ is a point inside $E$. $AB$ is a chord of $E$ through $P$ and $O$ is the center of $E$. How can I find the maximum value of $\frac{AP}{PB}$ as $A$ varies on $E$? Oh, yeah. We are only allowed to use affine properties to arrive at a solution.

Comment: When you say "affine" do you mean "special affine" (preserving area) or "general affine"?

Comment: general affine :)

Comment: No tangents, and no circle either: suggest new title...

Comment: @coffeemath You know what. You are correct about the tangents and circle title! I was thinking about some other problem while typing this one. But the question remains the same. Wow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that under an affine transformation, i.e. a projective transformation which preserves the line at infinity, all ellipses are equivalent. In other words, you might as well work with the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

The transformation $f : (x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ given by $u=\frac{1}{3}x$ and $v=\frac{1}{2}y$ is an orientation-preserving affine transformation which takes the ellipse $4x^2+9y^2=36$ onto the circle $u^2 + v^2 = 1$. Moreover, the point $P$ given by $(x,y)=(3/\sqrt{5},2/\sqrt{5})$ gets sent to the point $P'$ given by $(u,v)=(1/\sqrt{5},1/\sqrt{5})$.

In this case, the ratio $A'B':P'B'$ is maximised when $A'B'$ is a diameter. This happens when $A' = \pm(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. The points $(u,v)= \pm(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ correspond to $(x,y)=\pm(3/\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.

In terms of the language of ellipses, the chord $AB$ must pass through the midpoint of the chord joining the two foci of the ellipse.

Comment: GREAT!!! THANKS!

Comment: No worries. I'm pleased I could help.